# Why this behaviour when duplicating file descriptor?

Tags: unix, descriptor

I'm learning about file descriptors in unix at the moment:

```
echo 'bat' 1>&1 | sed 's/b/c/'
echo 'bat' 2>&1 | sed 's/b/c/'
```

The first line returns "cat cat" and the second line returns "bat cat" so I'm struggling to understand what is going on.
In the second line, FD2 (STDERR) is redirected to FD1 (STDOUT) which doesn't output anything. Then it outputs bat to FD1 AND pipes another bat to sed so we get bat and cat.
Why doesn't the same logic work for the first line? Wouldn't it output bat to STDOUT and then pipe another bat to sed to output "bat cat" also?

Comment: Both should return cat once as the bat output is piped to sed and convered to cat?

Comment: this is zsh. each command returns twice, with different results!